# How to read the below expression in "plain" English

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I'm going through the book "Haskell programming from first principles" and although the authors try to explain in detail how to reduce expressions, I still have trouble understanding how to read some expressions in the examples provided.

Let's assume the below expression:

`(λx.x)` Then if I understand things correctly this can be read as: "A lambda function, that accepts an argument `x` and returns (basically translating `.` as "returns") the same value `x`.

Now supposing that that we have the below expression:

`(λxy.xy)`, how do we read that expression in plain English? To make it even more complex the authors then expand `(λxy.xy)` to `(λxy.xy)(λz.a) 1`. How are these `z` and `a` appearing to the above expression? I was hoping that if I can properly transform the expression to plain English I'd be able to understand where `z` and `a` come from.

Answer (score 4):

In lambda calculus, values that are next to each other imply that the first value is being called as a function with the second value as an argument. `(λxy.xy)` is shorthand for `(λx.λy.xy)`, which means a function that takes an argument x then an argument y, and calls x with argument y. (if you're wondering why there's a function returning a function, it's due to [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Lambda_calculi)). To figure out what `(λxy.xy)(λz.a) 1` means, we have to take it step by step:

- Undo the shorthand: `(λx. λy. xy) (λz. a) 1`
- Apply first function (`λx`): `(λy. (λz. a) y) 1`
- Apply second function (`λy`): `(λz. a) 1`
- Apply third function (`λz`): `a`

So, we end up with whatever `a` is (probably an externally defined constant).